# How can i get from a directory string only the last subdirectory name and the file name?

Tags: c#

I have this line and how can I get only the last subdirectory name and the file name ?

```
    label13.Text = Path.GetFileName(file1);
```

Im getting only the file name: test.avi
If im not using the Path.GetFileName only file1 I will get something like:

```
http://users/test/test/program/test/test.avi
```

What I want to get is the last subdirectory name wich is: test and the file name: test.avi
So in label13 I will see: test/test.avi

How can I do it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just using `Path`:

```
Path.Combine(Path.GetFileName(Path.GetDirectoryName(path)), Path.GetFileName(path))
```

Comment: Note that this converts the forward slash to a backslash.

Comment: Yes but does it cause any problem?

Answer (score 2):

You can also split the string and grab the last 2 elements of the resulting array:

```
string path = "http://users/test/test/program/test/test.avi";
var elements = path.Split('/');
string result = elements[elements.Length-1] + "/" + elements[elements.Length];
System.Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following extension method to retrieve the character index to the nth-last index of the path separator and the return the correct substring:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static int NthLastIndexOf(this string value, char c, int n = 1)
    {
        if (count < 1)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("count must be greater than 0.");
        }

        var index = 1;
        for (int i = value.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if (value[i] == c)
            {
                if (index == n)
                {
                    return i;
                }
                index++;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
}

class Program
{
    public static string GetEndOfPath(string path)
    {
        var idx = path.NthLastIndexOf('/', 2);
        if (idx == -1)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("path does not contain two separators.");
        }

        return path.Substring(idx + 1);
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        var result = GetEndOfPath("http://users/test/test/program/test/test.avi");
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
}
```

The extension method `NthLastIndexOf` returns the zero-based index position of the nth-last occurrence of a specified Unicode character. The method returns -1 if the character is not found at least n times in the string.